# How to "disagree" with documentation tag proposal?

Tags: support, documentation

I have noticed that [wordpress-theming](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress-theming) is being proposed. In my opinion it would duplicate existing [WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/topics).

However I don't see a way to provide such feedback on proposal?

The only available action seems to be to commit to it?